Can't access element's properties using DOM in p5.js
I am trying to expand on The Coding Train's Monty Hall Problem demonstration using p5.js, and I am stuck in trying to implement an automatic mode.
Everything works fine, except that the background of the doors doesn't change color. Here is my code in p5.js's editor, as well as a snippet that follows:


const doors = [];
let state;
let pickedDoor;
let revealedDoor;
let switchButton, stayButton, playAgain, autoButton;
let autoVelocity;
let outcomeP;

let resultsP;

let totalStays = 0;
let totalSwitches = 0;
let switchWins = 0;
let stayWins = 0;

let auto = false;

function startOver(){
  state = "PICK";
  // Restart all the doors
  for (let door of doors){
    door.prize = "";
    door.html("");
    door.style("background-color", "#FFFF64");
  }
  // Pick a random winner
  const winner = random(doors);
  winner.prize = "";
  
  playAgain.hide();
  outcomeP.html("");
}

function setup() {
  noCanvas();
  
  // Create the doors
  for (let i=0; i<3; i++){
    doors[i] = createDiv();
    doors[i].parent("#doors");
    doors[i].class("door");
    doors[i].index = i;
    doors[i].mousePressed(pickDoor);
  }
  
  switchButton = createButton("switch");
  switchButton.mousePressed(playerSwitch);
  switchButton.hide();
  
  stayButton = createButton("stay");
  stayButton.mousePressed(playerStay);
  stayButton.hide();
  
  playAgain = createButton("play again");
  playAgain.mousePressed(startOver);
  playAgain.hide();
  
  autoButton = createButton("Start automatic mode");
  autoButton.mousePressed(toggleAuto);
  
  resultsP = createP();
  resultsP.class("results");
  
  outcomeP = createP();
  outcomeP.class("outcome");
  
  autoVelocity = createSlider(1, 1000, 950);
  
  startOver();
  
}

function pickDoor(){
  if (state == "PICK"){
    state = "REVEAL";
    
    if (auto){
      pickedDoor = random(doors); 
      autoButton.html("Stop automatic mode");
    } else {
      pickedDoor = this;
    }
    
    pickedDoor.style("background-color", "#9D9DFD");
    
    if (auto){
      setTimeout(reveal, 1000-autoVelocity.value());
    } else {
      reveal();
    }
  }
}

function reveal() {
  console.log("reveal");
  // Get all the doors that don't have the prize behind them
  const options = [];
  for (let i=0; i<doors.length; i++){
    const door = doors[i];
    if (i!== pickedDoor.index && door.prize !== ""){
      options.push(door);
    }
  }
  
  // Reveal a goat
  revealedDoor = random(options);
  revealedDoor.html(revealedDoor.prize);
  
  if (!auto) {
    switchButton.show();
    stayButton.show();
  } else {
    if (floor(random(0,2)) == 1){
      setTimeout(playerSwitch(), 1000-autoVelocity.value());
    } else {
      setTimeout(playerStay(), 1000-autoVelocity.value());
    }
    switchButton.hide();
    stayButton.hide();
  }
}

function playerSwitch() {
  totalSwitches++;
  let newPick;
  
  for (let i=0; i<doors.length; i++){
    let door = doors[i];
    if (door !== pickedDoor && door !== revealedDoor){
      newPick = door;
      break;
    }
  }
  pickedDoor = newPick;
  checkWin(true);
}

function playerStay(){
  totalStays++;
  checkWin(false);
}


function checkWin(playerSwitched) {
  switchButton.hide();
  stayButton.hide();
  
  // Reveal all the doors
  for (let door of doors){
    door.html(door.prize);
    door.style("background-color", "#FFFF64")
  }
  
  if (pickedDoor.prize == ""){
    outcomeP.html("You win!");
    pickedDoor.style("background-color", "#AFA");
    
    if (playerSwitched){
      switchWins++;
    } else {
      stayWins++;
    }
    
  } else {
    outcomeP.html("You lose!");
    pickedDoor.style("background-color", "#FAA");
  }
  
  // Statistics
  let switchRate = switchWins / totalSwitches;
  let stayRate = stayWins / totalStays;
  
  resultsP.html(`Total Switches: ${totalSwitches} <br/>
                 Switch Win Rate: ${nf(100*switchRate,2,2)}% <br/>
                 Total Stays: ${totalStays} <br/> 
                 Stay Win Rate: ${nf(100*stayRate,2,2)}% <br/><br/>
                 Total Plays: ${totalSwitches+totalStays}<br/>`);
  resultsP.show();
  
  if (!auto){
    outcomeP.show();
    playAgain.show();
  } else {
    playAgain.hide();
    startOver();
  }
}

function playAutomatically(){
  if (auto){
    startOver();
    autoButton.html("Stop automatic mode");
    reveal();
    
    setTimeout(playAutomatically, 1000-autoVelocity.value());
    
  } else {
      playAgain.show();
      autoButton.html("Start automatic mode");
  }
}

function toggleAuto(){
  auto = !auto;
  pickDoor();
  playAutomatically();
}

/*
function toggleAuto() {
  auto = !auto;
  if (auto) {
    pickDoor();
  } else {
    autoButton.html("Start automatic mode");
  }
  startOver();
}
*/
function draw() {
  background('#FFF');
}
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#doors{
  display: flex;
}

.results, .outcome {
  font-size: 19pt;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: New York Times;
}

button{
  font-size: 18pt;
  margin: 10px;
}

.door{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #FFFF64;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 64pt;
  margin: 10px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.4/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.4/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div id="doors"></div>
    </main>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>



The error I am getting is this:
TypeError: pickedDoor.style is not a function at /sketch.js:84:16. I'm pretty sure what this means is that, in the pickDoor() function, in line 78, when picking a random door using random(doors), somehow the door isn't the appropriate type of object. Other than this, I have no idea what could be the problem.
Since I am new to p5.js, and a beginner in JavaScript, I don't really even know how to debug this. I have tried console logging with console.log(pickedDoor) or console.log(str(pickedDoor)), but that just logs nothing and object Object, respectively.
For reference, here is The Coding Train's implementation using automatic playing. I have compared but I don't see where the code differs in a way that would be relevant.
Any help with this problem would be appreciated, thanks!

pickedDoor = this. What is this? It's window, not a door. Do you want something like doors[i].mousePressed(() => pickDoor(doors[i])); and add a door parameter to pickDoor so you can access the door that was picked?

Implementing this I still get the same error...  the problem is not in the doors[] array, I don't think (doors[i].mousePressed(() => pickDoor(doors[i])); is still using a window, right?)
To be clear, I have changed line 43 doors[i].mousePressed(pickDoor); to doors[i].mousePressed(() => pickDoor(doors[i]));,  line 74 function pickDoor()tofunction pickDoor(door), and line 82 pickedDoor = thistopickedDoor = door`.
